# How to avoid repetition when defining this nested map

Tags: dictionary, go, struct

In one of my json schema, I have a map like this

```
var deviceSchemaJson = map[string]interface{}{
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": map[string]interface{}{
        "application": map[string]string{
            "type": "string",
        },
        "hostname": map[string]string{
            "type": "string",
        },
        "ipaddress": map[string]interface{}{
            "oneOf": []map[string]string{{"format": "ipv4"},{"format": "ipv6"}},
            "type": "string",
        },
        "kernel_version": map[string]string{
            "type": "string",
        },
    },
    "type": "object",
}
```

How can I avoid defining `map[string]string` every time?

Comment: What problem do you have with the current structure that makes you search for an improvement?

Comment: i had to define `map[string]string` everytime.

Answer (score 2):

try this if that suites you better

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n",deviceSchemaJson)
}

var deviceSchemaJson = value{
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": value{
        "application": value{
            "type": "string",
        },
        "hostname": value{
            "type": "string",
        },
        "ipaddress": value{
            "oneOf": []valuestring{{"format": "ipv4"}, {"format": "ipv6"}},
            "type":  "string",
        },
        "kernel_version": valuestring{
            "type": "string",
        },
    },
    "type": "object",
}

type value map[string]interface{}

type valuestring map[string]string
```

https://play.golang.org/p/6Kq5pvXYvNm

Answer (score 0):

> How can I avoid defining `map[string]string` every time?

By defining types which represent your data structure.

```golang
type DeviceSchema struct {
    AdditionalProperties bool
    Properties Properties
    Type string
}

type Properties struct {
    Application string
    Hostname string
    IpAddress []map[string]string
    KernelVersion string
}

func main() {
    deviceSchemaData := DeviceSchema{
        AdditionalProperties: false,
        Properties: Properties{
            IpAddress: []map[string]string{{"format": "ipv4"},{"format": "ipv6"}},
        },
        Type: "object",
    }
    fmt.Println(deviceSchemaData)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/iHfoft1zyAn

Answer (score 0):

One way to simplify the definition would be:

```
func stringMap(s...string) map[string]string {
  ret:=map[string]string{}
  for i:=0; i<len(s);i+=2 {
     ret[s[i]]=s[i+1]
  }
  return ret
}

var deviceSchemaJson = map[string]interface{}{
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": map[string]interface{}{
        "application": stringMap("type","string"),
        "hostname": stringMap("type","string"),
        "ipaddress": map[string]interface{}{
            "oneOf": []map[string]string{stringMap("format","ipv4"),stringMap("format","ipv6")},
            "type": "string",
        },
        "kernel_version": stringMap("type","string"),
    },
    "type": "object",
}
```